# PQ - CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")?

Tags: powerquery

Is it possible to connect VBA user-defined functions to Power Query?
Can PQ operate with custom Excel's-like UDFs?
Just want to use VBA's regexps

```
Public Function RegExpTest(str As String, _
    Pattern As String, _
    Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional Multiline As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    RegExpTest = False
    If Not str Like "" And Not Pattern Like "" Then
        Dim RegExp As Object
        Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With RegExp
            .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
            .Multiline = Multiline
            .Pattern = Pattern
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        RegExpTest = RegExp.Test(str)
        Set RegExp = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PQ can't talk directly to VBA, but you can share data across Excel worksheets (i.e. load data to worksheet, than run VBA over the sheet).